# MySQL insert random rows from select

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a table set up like this -

```
Users
===========
id
userid
friendid
```

and another set up like this

```
Game_Objs
===========
id
obj_id
```

For testing, I need to insert a random number of obj_ids from Game_Objs into a new table associated with friendids, so something like this -

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Friend_Objs
-------------------------------------------------------------------
id                | friendid              | obj_id
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1                 | 123                   | aaa
1                 | 123                   | bbb
1                 | 123                   | ccc
1                 | 456                   | abc
1                 | 456                   | bbb
1                 | 456                   | cde
```

Where the number of obj_ids is random for each friendid.

Is this possible using just mysql? If not, what would be the best way to accomplish it in PHP?

Comment: I smell homework. Anyway, I dont know how to do it only mysql but with php its very possible just do a random for obj_id in php and put it in the query of Insert to executed in mysql.

Comment: Not homework, but my MySQL skills are definitely a sword that needs sharpened.

This is just a test case where we need a lot of data to pull from. The problem with doing it in PHP is that the Users table is 400k+ rows, and the game_objs table is 20k, so that's a lot of data for PHP to store. 

I was mostly looking for a mysql solution to this. Thanks for the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the following

```
$Query = "insert into `Friend_Objs` " . 
"values (1, 123, " . substr(str_shuffle("abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"), 0, 3);
```

Change the `3` to the length of string you want.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear, but Friend_Objs.obj_id has to be a value from Game_Objs.obj_id

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to load 600k random rows into a MySQL table fast: ( [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast) )

Integrate that with:

```
INSERT INTO table(column1, column2 ) SELECT ...
```

Use the select query in the above link that returns random rows.